# Are there unwanted consequences in swapping HDDs in a built-in dock?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a PC tower with a built-in hard-drive dock. Windows 10 is installed on an SSD drive, and I use an HDD — let's call it HDD1 — plugged into the built-in dock mostly for saving files. However, I *have* also installed a few programs on this HDD1.

I also have another HDD — let's call it HDD2 — that had its own (external) dock. However, the dock failed and now I'm left with the drive. I would like to insert this HDD2 in the built-in dock, to transfer some of the files.

**My question:**
Would there be any unintended consequences in removing HDD1 from the built-in dock to (temporarily) use HDD2? I obviously understand any e.g desktop shortcuts pointing to programs installed on HDD1 will not work, but I was wondering whether there might be some mix-up in the registry, or anything of the sort.

I expect it might be safer to swap the drives with the computer off. Are there any other things I need to consider?

**Edit:**
Both HDDs are SATA, as is the dock. It's physically possible to connect HDD2. My question is whether there could be any unwanted consequences in terms of OS stability, through the process of having some programs installed on a drive that will (temporarily) be absent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would there be any unintended consequences in removing HDD1 from the built-in dock to (temporarily) use HDD2? I obviously understand any e.g desktop shortcuts pointing to programs installed on HDD1 will not work, but I was wondering whether there might be some mix-up in the registry, or anything of the sort.

Registry keys that refer to external volumes don’t typically exist unless explicitly created by an application. Even if a registry key does exist, it won’t be used by Windows, or prevent Windows from booting.

Your existing external volume could be dismounted and Windows would continue to function.

> I expect it might be safer to swap the drives with the computer off. Are there any other things I need to consider?

Unless this SATA dock explicitly supports hot swapping, the machine absolutely should be turned off, before the drive is ejected.